# java 7 closeable PreparedStatement

Tags: java-7

Can anyone explain how to convert following code to JDK 7 style autoclosable???

```
PreparedStatement p = = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myTable(colName) VALUES(?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
p.setObject(1, obj);
int r = p.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = p.getGeneratedKeys();
if (null != rs && rs.next()) {
activityInfoId = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well found that you can not use statements like p.setObject(1,obj) in try ( ... )